# Grid tie inverter 200 W with low voltage auto disconnect

Tags: ac, relay, dc, inverter, solar-energy

I have a grid tie inver that produces at most any day 200 watts from my 12 V battery bank. I also have a adjustable auto low voltage disconnect circuit that disconnect the 12 V from inverter when voltage drops below set limit and then back on once it reaches the other set limit.

The first auto disconnect circuit I hooked up had the entire load of 200 watts running through it and it lasted about a day but got very hot and eventually burnt up. I have another low voltage disconnect circuit that is new that I don't want to burn up. I know I need a relay that uses the auto disconnect circuit as a remote and that can separately carry the constant 200 watts without burning up the relay.

What relay should I use?

I can use 12 V for the remote and the load side but preferably I would like to use 12 V for the switch and 120 VAC for load side. I'm just unsure what relay to use that can carry the constant load of 200 W with possibly on cloudy days very frequently turning on/off/on/off multiple times as voltage drops due to no sun.
The load is set at 200 watts anytime it is on.

Thanks.

Comment: The relay doesn't care about watts. It cares about current (so the contacts don't overheat) and voltage (which determines the required arc gap and switching speed). Once the contacts are closed it has no idea whether it's operating on a 12 V circuit or a 120 V circuit.

Comment: So if you had grid tie inverter converting12vdc  into 120vac at constant 200watts that you wanted a separate built circuit low dc voltage auto disconnect circuit to disconnect your inverter when dc voltage was to low but it could not handle more than 50 watts of current what relay would you use?

Comment: No alcohol was involved in last comment. Thanks for your advice and response

Comment: "50 watts of current" isn't a thing. Current is measured in amperes (amps).